# How to find IP address of ADSL modem?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump, debug, modem

Our fall back Internet connection uses a SpeedStream 4100 modem, which just broke, so I have replaced it with a new one. I need to configure it to bridge mode, but I can't even find its IP address.

According to [this page](https://www.jacksontechnical.com/article.htm?id=36) is the default IP `192.168.0.1` and a dhcp server should hand out IP addresses. I can't see it does that. Here is what I have done:

- Reset it to factory defaults by holding in the reset button.
- Connected it to my Fedora laptop with the straight RJ45 cable from the box.
- `service network restart` on by laptop with is configured to use DHCP.
- `dhclient -r` to ask for a new IP. Didn't work.
- Set my IP to `192.168.0.23` and netmask `255.255.255.0` but still can't access `192.168.0.1` from a browser.

**Question**

Can anyone give me some debug ideas how to figure out how to connect to the modem, as it doesn't seam to give out a DHCP address to my laptop?

Btw. Are there any chance that I need a crossover cable?

**Update**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/PUt11fyY) is what I see with `tcpdump` when using static IP and DHCP.

**Update 2**

The default IP is indeed `192.168.254.254` according to the manual which @DanianoVerzulli linked to, but I can still not connect to it. The manual said that visiting `http://speedstream` should give the interface. Notice no TLD.

`ethtool p3p1` gives me `Link detected: yes` with both straight and crossover cable.

Below have I set my IP to `192.168.0.23` and subnet `255.255.0.0` and also tried with dhcp where I can see

```
# ip -s link show p3p1
2: p3p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:67:b0:bf:18:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    60098      412      0       0       0       0
```

Here are tcpdumps when using a straight cable when I have turned off the modem and then on again.

[Static.pcap](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznvfbAbXQRPZVlmR0JNZEwtQ1k/view?usp=sharing)

[dhcp.pcap](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznvfbAbXQRPYXFOeEtia28zbzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Install `wireshark` on your laptop, and with it connected to the ADSL modem and start a packet capture. You should see some network traffic from the device that will reveal it's IP address.

Comment: The way the text is formatted on that link makes it difficult to read. And it is practically impossible to do any meaningful filtering to find out what is going on. It would be much more useful to look on a pcap dump. `tcpdump` can produce it if you add `-Uw filename.pcap`.

Comment: As a side note, please note that [on this page](http://www.speedguide.net/routers/siemens-speedstream-4100-adsl122-router-318) it's claimed that the default IP address is **192.168.254.254**

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli You are right. Very nice find! =) I can still not connect to it though, but updated OP with the requested info.

Comment: If the IP is 192.168.254.254, then 192.168.0.23 as your address probably won't work because the router is probably using 255.255.255.0 as the subnet mask. Use something like 192.168.254.23 instead.

Comment: @longneck I have now tried this, and I still not see any Rx traffic.

Comment: If it supports IPv6 you can find it's IP address using `ping6 -c2 ff02::1%eth0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is a modem and not a bridge? Some ISP's gave SpeedStream 4100/4200 to their customers where they were infact bridges.

You can test this by opening it, and if it doesn't have a CMOS battery, then it is a bridge and you can't connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are high that a `tcpdump -n -i eth0` launched on your Fedora box, once connected to the router, will show an ARP probe that, probably, the router will send to check if its LAN IP address is already in use somewhere else. This should happen shortly after the router is powered up. Also note that you will see your own traffic, with tcpdump, so take care to carefully follow the output stream.

As for tcpdump, it could be possibile to heavily limit your own generated traffic, by disabling Network-Manager and force the `eth0` to go "online". Anyway... this should not be necessary.

In case you router is **very silent** and don't tell anything, on the LAN, unless explicitely asked (...and so it doesn't check if its own IP address is already in use on the LAN), than you can do some test at ethernet/[ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) level, with the [`arping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping) utility. I'd suggest to setup your `eth0` with the IP address `192.168.0.23` (as you already did), but fixing the subnet mask at `255.255.0.0`. In this way, your host will consider the whole 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.254.0/24 **directly connected**, so to send, for them, proper ARP requests. With this setup you could run something like:

```
arping -I eth0 a.b.c.d
```

and see if a.b.c.d is connected to the LAN.

An arping to an IP address that is **not** connected to the LAN will result in an output that will simply hang, until you press CTRL-C, like in:

```
root@lbox:~# arping -I eth0 10.0.49.252
ARPING 10.0.49.252 from 10.0.49.1 eth0
^CSent 4 probes (4 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
```

while a succesfull one will produce an output similar to the common `ping`, like in:

```
root@lbox:~# arping -I eth0 10.0.49.254
ARPING 10.0.49.254 from 10.0.49.1 eth0
Unicast reply from 10.0.49.254 [00:1A:64:21:0A:9E]  0.746ms
Unicast reply from 10.0.49.254 [00:1A:64:21:0A:9E]  0.643ms
Unicast reply from 10.0.49.254 [00:1A:64:21:0A:9E]  0.637ms
Unicast reply from 10.0.49.254 [00:1A:64:21:0A:9E]  0.637ms
^CSent 4 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 4 response(s)
```

As a side note, please note that `arping` will work even if the host has a firewall configured (tipically a windows machine, with firewall up).

As for the crossover cable, I don't think you need it, anyway you can check if ethernet link is UP simply issuing a `ethtool eth0` and reading the output. Here below you can see a `Link detected: no`, that means that the `eth0` is **not** connected:

```
verzulli@iMac-Chiara:~$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    [...]
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    [...]
    Link detected: no
```

while here you can see the same `eth0` when the link is up:

```
verzulli@iMac-Chiara:~$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    [...]
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    [...]
    Link detected: yes
```

<strike>PS: Sorry to not provide links: I'm typing from my smartphone.</strike>

Comment: I have update the OP with `tcpdump` output. Can you see anything of interest? This is with a straight cable. http://pastebin.com/PUt11fyY

Comment: It seems all traffic captured has been generated by your local machine. Please, confirm it's directly attached to the SpeedStream. Also, let's check if your (directly connected....) PC, ever received traffic from your router with: "ip -s link show eth0". It surely sent traffic.... let's check the RX side (I'm assuming your PC and the SpeedStream are the only two hosts connected) .